# How can I change the arrow style in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jcombobox, synth

Let's say I want to use a custom image for the arrow in JComboBox, how can I do this?

I understand it's possible using the synth xml files, or maybe even UIManager.put(...), but I don't know how. All I want to do at this time is change the arrow image to something else, either programatically or even just overriding the image it uses. How exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can override `createArrowButton()` in [`BasicComboBoxUI`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxUI.html). [`BasicArrowButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicArrowButton.html) is a convenient starting point.

```
class ColorArrowUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {

    public static ComboBoxUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new ColorArrowUI();
    }

    @Override protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        return new BasicArrowButton(
            BasicArrowButton.SOUTH,
            Color.cyan, Color.magenta,
            Color.yellow, Color.blue);
    }
}
```

Then install it.

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
combo.setUI(ColorArrowUI.createUI(combo));
```

Comment: Not responsible for garish color scheme. :-)

Comment: for me ... is maybe safiest to extract JButton as JComponent from JComboBox and button.setIcon(), f.e. with ButtonModel for mousehover effect for JComboBox too..  +1 for BasicUI