# Change JComboBox Arrow's background color

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I found the following [solution for changing a JComboBox arrow's color](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aYC_-1tZ2ETwJ:192.9.162.102/thread.jspa%3FmessageID%3D10473156+MetalComboBoxButton+color+change&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a):

```
For JComboBox and Metal L&F
-- iterate recursively over the components of the JComboBox and grab a reference 
   to the button of class javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton
-- get the icon by getComboIcon()
-- create a BufferedImage (type ARGB) the size of the icon
-- paintIcon the icon to the Graphics context of the BufferedImage
-- iterate over the pixels of the BufferedImage and change any non-zero pixels 
   (by getRGB) to the color you want (by setRGB).
-- construct a new ImageIcon from the image
-- set the new icon to the button by setComboIcon
```

How exactly do you "paintIcon the icon to the Graphics context of the BufferedImage"?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
    int componentCount = comboBox.getComponentCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < componentCount; i++) {
        Component component = comboBox.getComponent(i);
        if (component instanceof MetalComboBoxButton) {
            MetalComboBoxButton metalComboBoxButton =
                (MetalComboBoxButton) component;
            Icon comboIcon = metalComboBoxButton.getComboIcon();
            BufferedImage bufferedImage =
                new BufferedImage(
                    comboIcon.getIconWidth(),
                    comboIcon.getIconHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            comboIcon.paintIcon(
                metalComboBoxButton, bufferedImage.getGraphics(), 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider using a custom instance of [`BasicArrowButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicArrowButton.html) in a `ComboBoxUI`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008587).