# How to create a simple look like Combobox in Java for Mac OS

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

The default Combobox in Mac OS is as follows:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10836207/Screen%20shot%202011-08-05%20at%209.53.48%20AM.png]

How can I change to following one?:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10836207/Screen%20shot%202011-08-05%20at%209.54.01%20AM.png]

**P.S.** - The Combobox is created in `JTable`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Check out the brilliant [MacWidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets)

Here are the key steps:

1. Create a `JComboBox` with the appropriate L&F.
2. Create a TableCellEditor with the comboBox, for example using [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#DefaultCellEditor%28javax.swing.JComboBox%29)
3. Set the editor on your JTable using [`setDefaultEditor(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29)

TableCellRenderer getDefaultRenderer(Class columnClass)

Comment: +1 for MacWidgets, although I'm not sure a renderer alone in sufficient.

Comment: Hi, If I follow your step, it will create the first Combobox in my question. I need some way to get the second one.

Comment: I would start looking into the L&F. I suspect it has two different looks based on the container...

Comment: One thing I should have made clear initially is that I want my Jcombobox to appear this way inside a jtable. The default look is very similar to a text cell inside a jtable, with the difference being that when you click the cell with the combobox a drop down arrow appears in the right hand side of the cell and clickable choices appear below.  What I want is for the drop down arrow of the jcombobox to ALWAYS be visible.  I know this is possible because I have seen examples of this in netbeans  guibuilder properties panel.

Answer (score 1):

The default UI delegate for `JComboBox` on Mac OS X is `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI`. You can replace it with your own variation of [`BasicComboBoxUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxUI.html). There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008447/how-can-i-change-the-arrow-style-in-a-jcombobox/3008587#3008587) and a more complete [example](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/source/browse/trunk/source/com/explodingpixels/macwidgets/plaf/HudComboBoxUI.java) in the [MacWidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) collection suggested by @Dilum.

Comment: Hi, do I have to override it to get the second style?

Comment: It looks like you're using Nimbus.