# Circle JSlider - Java program

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Can someone show me code that will set up a JSlider except, instead of a thumb, it is a circle? Specifically, instead of that little triangle which points to the current position, it is a blue circle of width 100;

Comment: same question as often: why? Standard - in both look and feel - components are standardized for a reason ...

Comment: because I'm customizing the slider. while it's java code, the look and feel of a final java application does not necessarily have to always be java-looking.

Comment: agreed, not necessarily java-whatever-that-means - but  it has to look consistent and be functional and usable. Getting both right is not trivial, big companies pay big money for user studies. Thinking you or me could get similar results is .. a bit over-optimistic ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Metal L&F you could extend javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalSliderUI and override the `horizThumbIcon` or `vertThumbIcon` to be your circle. Then set this UI to be UI you'd like for your sider using `slider.setUI()`

look at this the answer here which performs a change for a JComboBox [How can I change the arrow style in a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008447/how-can-i-change-the-arrow-style-in-a-jcombobox/3008587#3008587).

Comment: +1 Changing the `Icon` in `MetalSliderUI` seems convenient. See also these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992633/painting-the-slider-icon-of-jslider/6996263).

Comment: -1 for setting a ui delegate on a single component instance. That will not survive any updateUI nor be safely consistent across any the application.