# Add PropertyChangeListener to JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, propertychangelistener

How do I use `PropertyChangeListener` with `JComboBox`? When I write in editable `JComboBox`, I get the text written immediately because I changed the icon of the arrow button of the combobox; and key listeners aren't working any more.
This is what I tried, but I don't know how to complete:

```
editor = (JTextComponent) jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

editor.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) 
    {

    }       

});
```

Comment: What is a PropertyChangetableListener? I've never seen such a beast either in a program or in the API.

Comment: By the way, consider using a DocumentListener instead.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Or maybe better a DocumentFilter.

Comment: +1 thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels , i tried using  DocumentListener but it didnt work because i changed the arraw button icon of the jcombobox

Comment: @CalmSea Please, DON'T use `KeyListener` it's not the correct approach to monitor for changes to the editor. Also "+1" is used to indicate that you like the question and that you've updated the posters comment/question ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's a little difficult to understand what it is you're trying to achieve from your post, but if you're interested in knowing when the editor content is changed you could try

```
final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
combo.setEditable(true);
((JTextComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    protected void updatePopup() {

        if (combo.isDisplayable()) {

            if (!combo.isPopupVisible()) {

                combo.showPopup();

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updatePopup();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updatePopup();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updatePopup();
    }
});
```

Normally, I'd create a "DocumentHandler" as a concrete class and use that instead, but the example demonstrates the basic idea

**UPDATED with a UI example**

```
public class TestComboBox extends JFrame {

    public TestComboBox() {

        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

        /**** You have to do this first
         **** Doing this invalidates any previous listeners
         ****/
        combo.setUI(ColorArrowUI.createUI(combo));

        combo.setEditable(true);
        ((JTextComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            protected void updatePopup() {

                if (combo.isDisplayable()) {

                    if (!combo.isPopupVisible()) {

                        combo.showPopup();

                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updatePopup();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updatePopup();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updatePopup();
            }
        });

        combo.setModel(createComboBoxModel());

        add(combo);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    protected ComboBoxModel createComboBoxModel() {

        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        File file = new File("../TestWords/Words.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                model.addElement(text);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {

            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

        return model;

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
        new TestComboBox();
    }

    public static class ColorArrowUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {

        public static ComboBoxUI createUI(JComponent c) {
            return new ColorArrowUI();
        }

        @Override
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            return new BasicArrowButton(
                            BasicArrowButton.SOUTH,
                            Color.cyan, Color.magenta,
                            Color.yellow, Color.blue);
        }
    }
}
```

Set using the UI

[image: Set by UI]

Set using the painter

[image: Set By Painter]

**Updated**

This is the code that kleopatra showed you

```
Painter painter = new Painter<JComponent>() {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    }

};

JButton org = null;
for (int i = 0; i < combo.getComponentCount(); i++) {
    if (combo.getComponent(i) instanceof JButton) {
        org = (JButton) combo.getComponent(i);
        UIDefaults buttonDefaults = new UIDefaults();
        buttonDefaults.put("ComboBox:\"ComboBox.arrowButton\"[Enabled].foregroundPainter", painter);
        org.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
        org.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", buttonDefaults);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302423/230513).

Comment: +1 @trashgod thanks , but i tried using Ducument Listener and it didn't work.

Comment: +1 @MadProgrammer this is what i'm trying to do (see this link):       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040248/jcombobox-popup-menue

Comment: +1 i was suggested to use property change Listener to solve the problem, i searched about it , but didnt know how to use it or how it can solve the problem . any solution ????

Comment: @CalmSea, let me see if I can get this right.  You want the popup to be displayed when ever the user starts typing something into the field yes?  Did you try the example above?

Comment: @CalmSea I tried kleopatra's example without issue, I've tried Trashgods example without issue (although I had to make sure I set the listeners and UI in the correct order)

Comment: @CalmSea: Please edit your question to include your current working [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks a lot ,finally , the second picture is exatly what i want
can you give me the code of it please (using painter)

Comment: @CalmSea Sure, I literally copied from the post kleopatra did for you.