# Customize position of arrow on JComboBox (place centered on bottom)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, ribbon

I'd like to be able to make a `JComboBox` with the arrow centered, below the text, to look like the pictured buttons from Word.

[image: The]

I understand that the usage of the pictured buttons here differs from the usage of a JComboBox, but I'm more concerned about getting the arrow in the right position.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of a `JComboBox` is determined by the chosen Look & Feel's UI delegate, typically a subclass of `BasicComboBoxUI`. You can replace the delegate, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008587/230513), and paint the `arrowButton` where you want it. Related examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20%22extends%20BasicComboBoxUI%22).