# JComboBox changes the way it looks from in preview mode to compiling and running

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jcombobox

I am making an application using NetBeans in Java for the first time and I am encountering behavior I don't understand. When dragging a JComboBox into my app, it looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HySK3.jpg

Which I really do like the look of this. But when compiling and running my application it changes the look to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r0cL.jpg

I believe the solution is to override methods in BasicComboBoxUI as suggested in this stackoverflow question [How can I change the arrow style in a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008447/how-can-i-change-the-arrow-style-in-a-jcombobox) but my question is why does this happen? And is that the solution I am looking for? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Look&Feel of your application. This is usually the first item coded within the main() method and in NetBeans, I believe the default application look&feel is Nimbus. Change this look&feel to whatever you like. [Read this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels).

I think you can change the default Look&Feel by going into the menu items **Tools** -> **options** -> **Appearance** -> **Look&Feel** Tab -> Selected desired look&Feel from drop-down box.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so much!